# Why are .NET property wrappers bypassed at runtime when setting dependency properties in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am reading Adam Nathan's book "WPF 4 Unleashed" and there is the following warning on page 82:

> **.NET property wrappers are bypassed at runtime when setting dependency properties in XAML!**
>   Although the XAML compiler depends on
>   the property wrapper at compile time, WPF calls the underlying
>   GetValue and SetValue methods directly at runtime! Therefore, to
>   maintain parity between setting a property in XAML and procedural
>   code, it’s crucial that property wrappers not contain any logic in
>   addition to the GetValue/SetValue calls. If you want to add custom
>   logic, that’s what the registered callbacks are for. All of WPF’s
>   built-in property wrappers abide by this rule, so this warning is for
>   anyone writing a custom class with its own dependency properties.

My question is: Why? What are the reasons that WPF calls GetValue()/SetValue() instead of reading/setting a CLR property wrapper? If the reason is that reading/setting a property wrapper requires reflection, then WPF uses reflection much when constructing an object tree anyway, so is it really worth it to bypass using property wrappers and call GetValue()/SetValue() directly? Or avoiding Reflection is not the main reason for such a behavior?

**UPD.** Clemens quickly gave a correct answer, but I would add just one more quote from that MSDN page (as I understand StackOverflow prefers quotes to links):

> The type is looked up through a combination of xmlns and assembly
>   attributes, but identifying the members, determining which could
>   support being set as an attribute, and resolving what types the
>   property values support would otherwise require extensive reflection
>   using PropertyInfo. Because dependency properties on a given type are
>   accessible as a storage table through the property system, the WPF
>   implementation of its XAML processor uses this table and infers that
>   any given property ABC can be more efficiently set by calling SetValue
>   on the containing DependencyObject derived type, using the dependency
>   property identifier ABCProperty.

Comment: That's explained in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Clemens You should make that an answer.

Comment: Clemens, thank you. If you make an answer and include a quote from that page, I would gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is given in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The WPF XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties. This effectively
>   bypasses the property wrappers. When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.

and:

> For implementation reasons, it is computationally less expensive to
>   identify a property as a dependency property and access the property
>   system SetValue method to set it, rather than using the property
>   wrapper and its setter. This is because a XAML processor must infer
>   the entire object model of the backing code based only on knowing the
>   type and member relationships that are indicated by the structure of
>   the markup and various strings.