# WPF – Change Property Value in Setter of Another Property

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

In the following example of my **custom control**, why I can't change a **TransparentColor** property in a **setter** of a **SelectedColor** property? A solution with callback method works fine, what's the difference between them in the case of change another property?

---

```
public class MyColorPicker : Control
{
    static MyColorPicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyColorPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyColorPicker)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyColorPicker), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromRgb(0, 201, 201), OnSelectedColorChange));

    private static void OnSelectedColorChange(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var colorPicker = (MyColorPicker)sender;
        var selectedColor = colorPicker.SelectedColor;
        colorPicker.TransparentColor = Color.FromArgb(0, selectedColor.R, selectedColor.G, selectedColor.B);
    }

    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            // Why this not working? BorderStopColor = Color.FromArgb(0, value.R, value.G, value.B);
            SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey TransparentColorPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("TransparentColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyColorPicker), new PropertyMetadata(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 201, 201)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransparentColorProperty = TransparentColorPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public Color TransparentColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(TransparentColorProperty); }
        protected set { SetValue(TransparentColorPropertyKey, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter of a CLR wrapper for a dependency property should *only* call the `SetValue` method to set the actual value of the dependency property.

*Any* other logic should be implemented in the callback.

Also note that the CLR property wrappers are bypassed at runtime when setting dependency properties in XAML (but the callbacks are not):

[Why are .NET property wrappers bypassed at runtime when setting dependency properties in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550381/why-are-net-property-wrappers-bypassed-at-runtime-when-setting-dependency-prope)